# extjs Image in listView with tooltip and conditional colors

Tags: javascript, listview, extjs

I am developing a listView with very limited space in width, so I come with idea that some information (like agent who create that record) can be replaced with an icon (of human) and th full information (first and last name) displayed when mouseOver (like a tooltip).

1. how to place an image on listView row (I think about 2 kinds: red shirt and blue skirt icon)
2. how to implement tooltip on it

?

EDIT: Also I am looking for way to conditionally change backgroud color of the cell: if hidden column "reason" = 1, column "AAA" will have red backgroud color, if = 2 column "BBB" and ....

Help will be welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `tpl`, that's what it's for:

```
columns: [
  {
    header: 'Agent',
    tpl: '<img src="{url}" ext:qtip="{tooltip}"/>'
  }
]
```

Instead of `<img>` you might want to create an element with background image. Or you might want to do choose the image conditionally. Read the documentation for [Ext.XTemplate](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.XTemplate) - it's all there.

But for background color you might be better off using [GridPanel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.GridPanel) instead - there you can easily set styles for a cell (using renderer) or even row (using getRowClass). ListView is a bit limited in that regard.

Comment: It seems like what I look for it fully solved first part. Thank you! I would like to stay away from GridPanel because my component is for display only and it too much turning off in GridPanel, so if can use lightweight listView I will preffered it. Is this conditional backgrouds could be implemented? Do you have solution for this ?

Comment: All I can say, is that adding styles to ListView rows is not going to be easy. You either have to dive inside ListView source and change the templates used for rendering rows. Or you could wait until ListView is rendered, and loop over the rows with Ext.DomQuery dynamically adding class for each row.